# Can we convert the equation in an equivalent one with one parameter?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, parametrization

We are given lines of the form \begin{align*}&x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \\ &y=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+c\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{align*} Is it possible to convert the second one in a form of the first one, i.e. with just one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It would only be possible if the vectors following b and c were linearly dependent, i.e. multiples of each other.

Comment: I am trying to apply the following method: Let $G$ and $H$ be points of the lines $g:\vec{x}=\vec{p}+s\cdot \vec{u}$ and $h:\vec{x}=\vec{q}+t\cdot \vec{v}$ respectively, and it holds that $\vec{GH}\cdot \vec{u}=0$ and $\vec{GH}\cdot \vec{v}=0$, then $|\vec{GH}|$ is the distance of the lines $g$ and $h$. $$$$ But the given equation of $y$ is in a different form. How can we apply that method here?

Comment: The second equation represents a plane. Ensure that $\vec{GH}$ is orthogonal to the *three* directions given to find the minimal distance.

Comment: So in this case we have to find the points  $G$ and $H$ such that $\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=0$ ? Or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: In this case we want to calculate the distance between a line and a plane, correct?

Comment: We are given \begin{align*}&X=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}+a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\mid r\in \mathbb{R}\right \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4 \\ & Y=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+c\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mid s,t\in \mathbb{R}\right \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4\end{align*} I want to calculate the distance between $A$ and $B$. It holds that $d(X,Y)=\min \{d(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$. And for $d(x,y)$ I want to use the method I described before.

Comment: So in this case we have to find the points  $G$ and $H$ such that $\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\vec{GH}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=0$. I have found then the points and so we get $|\vec{GH}|=\sqrt{2}$. This is equal to $d(x,y)$, right? Will this be then also the distance $d(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, correct on all counts. The points $x$ and $y$ are the (in this case unique) points of $X$ and $Y$ for which the distance is minimized.

Comment: If there weren't unique that would mean that we couldn't calculate all the parameters $a, b, c$ ? In this case $x$ and $y$ are the only points such that the vectr $\vec{GH}$ is orthogonal to the three vectors, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may write it without any parameter at all.  Given
$$E\colon \vec y=\vec a+b\vec u+c\vec v,$$
a vector $\vec y$ satisfies the equation iff the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $\vec u$, $\vec v$ and $\vec y-\vec a$ equals zero, that is, the Gram-determinant of the three vectors vanishes:
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
\langle \vec u,\vec u\rangle & \langle \vec u,\vec v\rangle &\langle \vec u,\vec y-\vec a\rangle\\
\langle \vec v,\vec u\rangle & \langle \vec v,\vec v\rangle & \langle \vec v,\vec y-\vec a\rangle\\
\langle \vec y-\vec a,\vec u \rangle & \langle \vec y-\vec a,\vec v\rangle &\langle \vec y-\vec a,\vec y-\vec a\rangle
\end{pmatrix}=0.$$

EDIT: If you have orthonormal $\vec u$ and $\vec v$  plugging in any vector $\vec y$ in the above determinant will give you the distance from $\vec y$ to the $2$-dimensional plane $E$.

Comment: Ah ok! I am aksing this because I want to calculate the distance between $x$ and $y$ by the following method: Let $G$ and $H$ be points of the lines $g:\vec{x}=\vec{p}+s\cdot \vec{u}$ and $h:\vec{x}=\vec{q}+t\cdot \vec{v}$ respectively, and it holds that $\vec{GH}\cdot \vec{u}=0$ and $\vec{GH}\cdot \vec{v}=0$, then $|\vec{GH}|$ is the distance of the lines $g$ and $h$.  $$$$ But in this case $y$ is not in the form described at the method. So how do we proceed?

Comment: I got stuck right now. Can we not use the method of my previous comment in this case?

Comment: In case $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ aren't parallel divide the Gram-determinant of $\vec u$, $\vec v$ and $\vec p-\vec q$ by the Gram-determinant of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.